# how to create a keyboard shortcut to launch xcode on a Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I did prefs > keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > (+) > title = Xcode and shortcut Shift-Ctrl-X
but it doesn't do anything.  Ctrl-X fails too.

Answer (score 1):

Try logging out and back in so that the display server refreshes

Comment: Done, but Still doesn't work.